# html getting two divs to match up in height

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with getting two divs in html to end in the same exact spot. This snippet will pretty much explain the isue:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 89.7%;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tabContent {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#divTableList,
.contentDiv {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.contentDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 89.7%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}

#divTableList {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 10%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tablinksimage {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.tablinksimagemain {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


.tablinks:hover,
.menulinks:hover,
.tablelinks:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tablinks.active,
.menulinks.active,
.tablelinks.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #3f51b5;
}

.tablinksimagemain.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tablinksimagemain:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="tabDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; visibility: visible">
    <div class="tab">
      <img src="img/table.png" class="tablinksimagemain active" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabContent', 0)">
      <img src="img/table-structure.png" class="tablinksimagemain" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabStructure', 1)">
      <img src="img/table-info.png" class="tablinksimagemain" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabInfo', 2)">
      <img src="img/proc.png" class="tablinksimagemain" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabProc', 3)">
      <img src="img/table-query.png" class="tablinksimagemain" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabQuery', 4)">
      <img id="imgLogout" class="tablinksimage" src="img/logout.png">
      <img id="imgRefresh" class="tablinksimage" src="img/refIcon.png">
    </div>
    <div id="divTableList">

    </div>
    <div id="tabContent" class="tabContent" style="display: block">
      <div id="contentDivContent" class="contentDiv">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabStructure" class="tabContent" style="display: none">

    </div>

    <div id="tabInfo" class="tabContent" style="display: none">

    </div>
    <div id="tabProc" class="tabContent" style="display: none">

    </div>

    <div id="tabQuery" class="tabContent" style="display: none">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see the div for the main content goes further than the the div on the left, I know this is due to the menubar but I'm confused as they are both of their heights are set to 100% as is the container they are both in.

I messed around with the percentages to get them to match up which brings me to my second issue: they match up on my screen resolution but they will no longer match up as soon as the resolution is changed (even opening the javascript console causes it).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I always thought setting the heights to 100% meant that it would stop at the height limit of the body.

Any ideas?

Comment: <div class="tab"> doesn't have height 100%. Isn't that the problem?

Comment: @audiodude that div shouldn't be @ 100% height as it's the menubar up top, the bottom line of the div below that (with class tabContent) and the div "divTableList" should be about the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of confusion may be that height percentages like "100%" don't actually "divide up" the height of the containing element. They simply resolve to a precise value based on the height of the containing element.

So you are free to have the following

```
<style>
   .parent {
     height: 100px;
   }
   .child {
     height: 50%;
   }
</style>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">a</div>
  <div class="child">b</div>
  <div class="child">c</div>
</div>
```

The children will each be 50px high. This means, of course, that there will be 3 x 50px or 150px of content and the content will overflow the parent div. That's fine too: HTML doesn't require that divs fit inside their containers.

This is basically what is happening in your snippet. The menu takes up some room, then the other div takes up 100% of, not the remaining room, but of the total size of the containing div. This makes it overflow the body and thus looks like the one on the left is too small.

One solution, in browsers that support it, is to use:

```
div.tab {
  height: 100px; // or whatever you want
}

.tabcontent {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

In other browsers, the answer is trickier.